# Vba want user to force fill form when not filled programme should not continue futher

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a form that a user should fill and if certain fields are not filled the form should not continue further but it still does may be I am not see some thing help please

this is  under the button presed  If Me.cbTyreNsf.value = " " Then

```
    MsgBox "You must complete the Wheel Nsf value", vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End If

If Me.cbTyreNsR.value = "" Then

    MsgBox "You must complete  Wheel Nsr value", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

the function called
 Call CheckifRecordExistOnWheelTable
```

the code for the function
 Select Case avar
    Case "NULL"
        Call insertWheel
    Case Else
        Call updateWheel
    End Select

and the code for the function called by the function

```
 nssf = Me.cbTyreNsf.value

Select Case nssf
Case "0"
    MsgBox " Please enter the NSF tyre value", vbCritical
    Me.cbTyreNsf.SetFocus
   ' MsgBox "about to exit"
    Exit Sub

Case Else
    nsf = CInt(nssf)
End Select
```

any help please i have been on it for 24 hours counting tried every thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a problem:

```
nssf = Me.cbTyreNsf.value
```

it does not pass any value to nssf if there is no value in the cbTyreNsf. (try msgbox(nssf) at that point. It will give you blank message box). If you want to test it using your current select case then you can try checking length of the value which will be 0 for empty cbTyreNsf.

```
nssf =Len(Me.cbTyreNsR.value)
```

Comment: I am expecting an integer